# Wordpress Page Template Updates not showing on website, unless I make a new page

Tags: wordpress, ftp, rackspace-cloud

The website I am currently working on (http://ignitingthesixthsense.com/launch-1) is failing to reflect the changes I make in the theme files, unless I make a new WordPress page.  For example I will update a page template file, refresh the page in the web-browser, and the changes do not show.  However, if I make a new page in WordPress, apply the page template I just updated, and publish page, the updates are shown.

This issue is seen across all browsers, clearing the cache does not fix it.  And this issue only happens on this domain.  I have replicated this theme on this domain: http://jltest.biz/test-1 and the problem is not there.

The first domain (the problem one) is hosted through RackSpace's cloud servers.  The second one is hosted through HostGator, if that means anything.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Rackspace hosting.  I contacted their support and they told be they needed to reset the website supercaching which they did for me.  And now the problem is resolved.